# "Рассупонилось солнышко"

Tags: старославянский

Читала тут недавно одну книгу, где пытались изобразить народную речь в противовес речи нейтрально-современной. И герои употребляли всякие выражения, вроде "надоть", "что ли ча" и т.д. в таком роде.
Но мне бы хотелось узнать, насколько такой вот "сельский" говор можно назвать народным языком и почему он так отличается от языка "городского"? Или же подобные попытки изобразить "русскую речь" - это что-то вроде знаменитого "Рассупонилось солнышко"?

Answer (score 1):

Довольно сложно ответить на вопрос "на сколько". И как это сделать? Не можем же мы рассчитать процентное соотношение?

Единственное, о чём мы можем говорить: выявлять причину такого различия деревенской и городской лексики. Как человек, живущий в непосредственной близи от деревни, могу сказать, что действительно: чем дальше в лес, тем больше дров. Жителям деревни более свойственно Г-эканье, употребление анахронизмов, а так же произношение "что", вместо разговорного "што" (по крайней мере при чтении). С чем это может быть связанно? На ум, первым делом приходит, то что, людям в городе чаще приходится участвовать в бюрократической волоките. В документации, разумеется, просторечие недопустимо, а потому, со временем, мог сформироваться "деловой стиль общения", свидетельствующий о принадлежности к некой "элите". Кроме того, нужно учитывать, что в городе приток приезжих больше, равно как и информационных источников (телевизор, радио), где так же придерживаются более прогрессивных выражений, избегая просторечье, а потому, человек, пребывающий в такой информационной среде, автоматически будет эти языковые стандарты как норму. В деревне такого нет, там всё более статично: одни и те же люди, одни и те же семьи, и одни и те же выражения, слова и архаизмы, передающиеся сквозь поколения.